# Python functions: recursion. lambda, ets

Tags: python, function

Write a fibonacci function that takes a number n (serial number) and returns a number from a list of Fibonacci numbers. Solve the problem with recursion.
Hint: Fibonacci numbers are a sequence of numbers where each element is calculated as the sum of the previous two. The sequence itself starts like this: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...

Example:
answer = fibonacci(5)
print(answer) # 3

answer = fibonacci(6)
print(answer) #5

I did it, but I don't know how to make a list start with zero
Can you help me?

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n in (1, 2):
        return 1
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)

n = int(input("n = "))
print(fibonacci(n))
```

Comment: If `n` is 1 you should return `0`, if `n` is 2 you should return `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your base condition to

```
if n in (1, 2):
   return n-1
```

to make sure you are counting 0 as well (as stated in the comment)